# You are in a box

Tags: situation

Imagine that you are in a box.

There are no windows, doors or exits of any kind.

You have no tools of any sort.

How do you get out?

Comment: Why is this off topic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is the answer...

> Imagine yourself out of it? The box only exists in your imagination, so if you imagine yourself out of it, you will be out of the box.

Answer (score 5):

You must probably:

> Think (yourself) out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

A box normally is made of:

> Paper or wood.

So you could just:

> Kick the walls with the most strength and violence that you could, until you break it and set yourself free.

Answer (score 1):

> just get out of your imagination

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE. Please consider using the spoiler template `>!` to hide your answer as other answerers do.